# [Jira][Java] Reading Excel-File from Unix-Server

Tags: java, linux, excel, apache-poi, jira

I need to read an Excel-File from an Unix-Server but my my Script (Java) continuously fails.

My Code:

```
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists())
    Sheet mySheet = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file)).getSheetAt(0);
```

I am using the following jars:

```
dom4j.jar
xmlbeans-5.2.4.jar
```

If I use these jars additional:

```
poi-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-shemas-3.9.jar
```

I Get an this error:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !
```

If I use these jars additional:

```
poi-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-shemas-3.11.jar
```

I Get an this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller
```

although this class is in poi-ooxml-shemas-3.11.jar.

Does anyone know how to handle this? Thanks for your help.

PS: I have no problems opening the xlsx-File with Excel

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us a piece of code, and look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI? And what happens when you open with [a File directly, not an InputStream, as explained in the documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)?